# Why would I use one JVM over another?

Tags: java, jvm

I strongly suspect that this question will not be a good fit for the Q&A format, but I'm struggling to find the correct words - feel free to reedit the question.

So I'm looking at [Wikipedia's long list of java virtual machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) and I find myself wondering, given that Java is a portable language why someone would choose one JVM over the other? Is it a performance thing? Are some more secure?

Comment: Joe, I edited your question to make it clear that you were asking about using one JVM over another (e.g., Oracle's Hot Spot vs Skelmir's CEE-J). Feel free to roll back the edit if that's not what you meant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first reason is that the JVM itself is not written in Java, and is not portable across OSes. So you'd better choose a Windows VM if your OS is Windows, and a Linux VM if you run on Linux.

The second reason is that new versions of the language need new versions of the JVM. So for example, a Java 7 VM won't be able to run programs written using Java 8 Lambdas.

Then as usual with all the products: some are more efficient in some areas than others. Some are open-source and others aren't. Some are specialized for a given kind of problem and others are more general, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would pose a counter question.

All cars provide a means for transportation, why choose one car over another?

Sun/Oracle just provides a specification that all JVM implementors need to follow.

You can view a JVM as a product. Different JVM vendors provide extra features/enhancements while adhering to the underlying specification which is sort of a Lowest Common Denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The newer versions have fixes with respect to bugs, security issues, etc., many enhancements in syntax (I know, syntactic sugar is the right word) and performance.

Comment: There are syntax changes between JVMs?

Comment: Ya, some additions have been made, for example the for-each was introduced in 1.5, the try with resources was introduced in 1.7, etc.

Answer (score -1):

In newer version there is more enhancement in performance.The garbage collection algorithm is more efficient than the previous one.So,it would be good idea to move to new one for better performance.

Comment: Do you have any links/facts that can back up your statements? BTW I didn't downvote...

Comment: Those are some of the enhancements for one specific Oracle VM release. The answer surely does not hit the question´s nail...